# clang: error: unknown argument: '-no-vec'

Tags: c++, macos-sierra, auto-vectorization

I'm trying to compile some things in c++ (on macOS 10.12.6) using different options and receive this kind of error with options like `-no-vec`, `-vec-report` but also more common things like `g++-6`.
I'm not new to c++ but I used to code some years ago (on linux, never mac or any other thing), I'm currently using geany and just compiling it on the terminal. I tried to look for other questions on `clang` errors but they just don't seem to fit this, maybe I need some very elementary help to understand where I should look to fix this.

Comment: And does clang have a option '-no-vec'?

Comment: Why did you add the `-no-vec` and `-vec-report` argument and why do you think you need to use them ? Since clang does not understand these arguments, remove them.

Comment: clang is not g++, it doesn't have the same command line arguments

Comment: @nos
I’m trying these options because I want to work with auto-vectorisation. I’m following this guide: [link] (https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/8c/a9/CompilerAutovectorizationGuide.pdf) and some examples from my teacher.  
I added `-no-vec` to verify that the execution time is slower without auto-vectorisation. And I added `-vec-report` just to have a confirmation whether auto-vectorisation is happening or not. 
I don’t really need any of them, I just wanted to see them at work, because I’m trying to learn, so I would like to understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: @manni66, @Caleth 
Sorry for my noobness but I’m not sure what you mean. I’m compiling like this: `g++ -std=c++11 -march=native -O3 -o prog code.cpp -g` and adding the mentioned options to this. I’m doing so thinking I’m passing options to `g++`, are you saying that I’m actually passing options to `clang`? Why so and what can I do to achieve what I wanted?

Comment: macOS uses clang as compiler. g++ is only another name to make old build scripts happy. Try `g++ --version`

Comment: @Pandi The documentation you found at https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/8c/a9/CompilerAutovectorizationGuide.pdf is for ICC, the C++ compiler made by Intel, it is a different product/compiler than what you have, that documentation does not apply to the clang (the default compiler in OSX) nor the gcc compiler. perhaps you have better luck with this documentation: https://llvm.org/docs/Vectorizers.html

Comment: Ok, I got it!! Thank you all :)